# не реализуется getName() в нити

Tags: java, task

```
/* 
    Задача
    Читайте с консоли имена файлов, пока не будет введено слово «exit«.
Передайте имя файла в нить ReadThread.
Нить ReadThread должна найти байт, который встречается в файле максимальное число раз, и добавить его в словарь resultMap,
где параметр String — это имя файла, параметр Integer — это искомый байт.
Закрыть потоки.
    */   

 public class Solution {
        public static Map<String, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            while(true){
                String name = reader.readLine();
                if (name.equals("exit"))
                    break;
                ReadThread thread = new ReadThread(name);
                thread.start();
            }
        }
        public static class ReadThread extends Thread {
            public ReadThread(String fileName){
                super(fileName);
                }
                //implement constructor body
            }
            public void run() {
            try {
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(getName()); // getName() везде красный
                ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
                while (in.available()>0){
                    list.add(in.read());
                }
                for (int i = 0;i<list.size();i++) {
                    int d = Collections.frequency(list,list.get(i));
                    map.put(d,list.get(i));
                }
                TreeMap<Integer, Integer> maps = new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>(map);
                List keyList = new ArrayList(maps.keySet()); // тут я просто не знаю как найти последний элемент в мапе сделал через лист
                resultMap.put(getName(), keyList.get(keyList.size()-1));
            }
            catch (IOException e){
            }

            }
        }
```

Сделал такую реализацию пока не знаю правильно или нет. Загвоздка заключается в том что при написании getName() в методе run он загорается красным (собственно вообще при начале написания get из возможных вариантов idea выдает только getClass() типа что то блокирует вообще любую реализацию get если я создаю новый класс делаю там нить то с getName() все нормально)  типа такого метода нет хотя он должен возвращать имя данной нити подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка ну и по коду если есть какие то косяки заранее благодарен.

Comment: У вас лишняя закрывающая скобка в конструкторе

Comment: Спасибо глупая ошибка...